# Azure Timer Function-Dependency Injection

Tags: azure, .net-core, timer, azure-functions

I'm creating Azure timer function to perform certain task on timely basis,I have added the required code for DI ,but whenever I run my application I get an error.

[image]

```
public class FunctionDeleteInactiveAccounts
{
    public readonly IDeleteInActiveAccount _deleteInActiveAccount;
    public FunctionDeleteInactiveAccounts(IDeleteInActiveAccount deleteInActiveAccount)
    {
        _deleteInActiveAccount = deleteInActiveAccount;
    }

        [FunctionName("FunctionDeleteInactiveAccounts")]
        public  void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            //log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now} and {_deleteInActiveAccount.DeletePastYearsInActiveUsers()}");
        }
    
}

//Startup.cs
[assembly:FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace PortalSecurityTimer_Functions
{
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IDeleteInActiveAccount, DeleteInActiveAccount>();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/issues/54) with version 1.1.0 of [Azure.Functions.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions), I suggest you downgrade it to 1.0.0 and check if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks..! it worked , but can you tell me what is the problem with upgraded version as I'm using V3

Comment: @VishalDhasal Sadly I don't know, make sure to add a reaction and a comment to that issue on GitHub, so the community behind that package knows it's a priority